# how to import some xyz.war file into the eclipse ide

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide, liferay-aui

Hello Stack overflow,

I am using liferay portal-6.0.0 version and I have a "greeting.war" file.

The WAR file deploys correctly, shows the portlet in `Add Category` and also after adding to the page display the output properly.

Now I wanted to get the code of that war file and want to import that code into the eclipse  as a `greeting-portlet` (i.e as a liferay project).

so I hope some help from you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the greeing.war has the embedded source code inside of it (WEB-INF/src) you can do the following:

1. [Install Liferay IDE plugins into Eclipse](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/installati-6)
2. Download a 6.0.x Liferay Plugins SDK [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/6.0.6/) and extract the plugins SDK to a directory
3. Add this SDK in your Liferay IDE preferences *Window > Preferences > Liferay > Installed SDKs*
4. Download Liferay Portal tomcat bundle 6.0.6 if needed [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/6.0.6/)
5. Unzip tomcat bundle
6. Setup Liferay Portal Tomcat Runtime in Eclipse, *File > New > Server > Liferay > Liferay Tomcat 6.0*
7. Rename greeting.war to greeting-portlet.war
8. From Eclipse open the *File > Import > Liferay > Liferay Binary Plugin*
9. Browse to the greetings-portlet.war file
10. Select the 6.0.x SDK you configured
11. Select the 6.0 target runtime you configured.
12. Press Finish

The wizard will create a new portlet project in the SDK and then copy all of the WAR resources into the new project automatically.